# R Map returning 2 different data.frame, using by bind_rows

Tags: r, purrr

I have a list of .csv files that I am trying to filter one by one (I can't filter when regrouped because I have too much data to load it at the same time).

I want :

- To filter my data, then aggregate it in one single data.frame
- To have a count of the data I filtered

Here is a (fake) example of my data :

```
library(tidyverse)
df_list=data.frame(a=seq(1,20,1), b=seq(41,60,1), c=seq(81,100,1)) %>% map(~{ 
  data.frame( a=.x, b=.x*2, c=.x*3)})
```

I then managed to do :

```
regrouped_data=df_list %>% map(~{
# Filter
  d2=.x %>% filter(a>5) 
# Count
  print(
    tribble(~date,~initial,~final,
            "name",nrow(.x),nrow(d2)
            )
  )
  return(d2)
}) %>% bind_rows()
```

The problem is : I need all the data.table to be assembled in one (because I have a lot of  files to filter). How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be nice to lay everything out so the logic is clear in a straightforward loop:

```
 filterCount <- function(){
  
  for(i in 1:length(df_list)){
    
    data_flt <- df_list[[i]] %>% 
      filter(a>5)
    
    count_flt <- tibble(date = i,
                        nrow.total = nrow(df_list[[i]]),
                        nrow.flt = nrow(data_flt))
    
    if(i == 1){
      
      data_out <- data_flt
      count_out <- count_flt
      
    } else {
      
      data_out <- bind_rows(data_out, data_flt)
      count_out <- bind_rows(count_out, count_flt)
      
    }
    
  }

  return(list(data_out, count_out))
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming here that the `date` would be name in the list, you can access names with `imap` & co through `.y`.

First example keeps counts and data.frame names together with data, in separate columns.

```r
library(tidyverse)

regrouped_data <- imap_dfr(df_list, 
                           ~ filter(.x, a > 5) %>% 
                             mutate(date = .y,
                             initial = nrow(.x),
                             final = n()))
regrouped_data %>% 
  select(date:final) %>% 
  distinct()
#>   date initial final
#> 1    a      20    15
#> 2    b      20    20
#> 3    c      20    20

as_tibble(regrouped_data)
#> # A tibble: 55 × 6
#>        a     b     c date  initial final
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <int> <int>
#>  1     6    12    18 a          20    15
#>  2     7    14    21 a          20    15
#>  3     8    16    24 a          20    15
#>  4     9    18    27 a          20    15
#>  5    10    20    30 a          20    15
#>  6    11    22    33 a          20    15
#>  7    12    24    36 a          20    15
#>  8    13    26    39 a          20    15
#>  9    14    28    42 a          20    15
#> 10    15    30    45 a          20    15
#> # … with 45 more rows
```

Here data and count are in separate  data.frames and `imap()` returns list of lists. From this, data & count can be conveniently extracted with `map_dfr()`

```r
regrouped_data <- imap(df_list, 
                      ~ {
                        data = filter(.x, a > 5)
                        count = tibble(date = .y,
                                       initial = nrow(.x),
                                       final   = nrow(data))
                        list(data  = data, 
                             count = count)
                      })

map_dfr(regrouped_data, "count") 
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   date  initial final
#>   <chr>   <int> <int>
#> 1 a          20    15
#> 2 b          20    20
#> 3 c          20    20
map_dfr(regrouped_data, "data") %>% as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 55 × 3
#>        a     b     c
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     6    12    18
#>  2     7    14    21
#>  3     8    16    24
#>  4     9    18    27
#>  5    10    20    30
#>  6    11    22    33
#>  7    12    24    36
#>  8    13    26    39
#>  9    14    28    42
#> 10    15    30    45
#> # … with 45 more rows
```

Example data:

```
df_list <- data.frame(a = seq(1, 20, 1), 
                      b = seq(41, 60, 1), 
                      c = seq(81, 100, 1)) %>% 
  map(~ {
  data.frame(a = .x, b = .x * 2, c = .x * 3)
})
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>